# Why am I receiving an error when installing Image Processing Toolbox from ATOMS in Scilab 2023 versions?

Tags: image-processing, scilab

I tried Installing Image processing module from ATOMS - Module Manager in Scilab 2023.0.0 & Scilab 2023.1.0  but getting error while installing. but installed properly in Scilab 6.1.0

```
atomsInstall: Error while building the toolbox 'C:\Users\ME\AppData\Roaming\Scilab\scilab-2023.0.0\atoms\x64\IPCV\4.1.2'.
```

Can i know why it is not installing / or any changes i have to do

Comment: IPCV has not been recompiled for Scilab 2023.x. 
The best place to ask for it is to post a comment @ https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/IPCV/#leave_a_comment
after being logged to your Gitlab account (that then as well will allow you to post some bug reports @ https://gitlab.com/scilab/scilab/-/issues/?sort=updated_desc&state=opened )

Answer (score 0):

The IPCV toolbox has just been recompiled today for Windows. You should be able to install it with

```
atomsSystemUpdate
atomsInstall IPCV
```